# how to sum by different level with a dict in python

Tags: python, pandas

e.g.:

```
example = {
    '1': nan, '1.1': nan, '1.1.1': nan, '1.1.1.1': 3.45,
    '1.1.1.2': 6.72, '1.1.1.3': 2.89, '1.1.1.4': 4.62,
    '1.1.2': 5.35, '1.1.3': 1.21, '1.1.4': 9.86,
    '1.2': 3.36, '1.3': 8.92
}
```

Of course it is only a part. The whole has 5 level at most.

I want to calculate `1.1.1=1.1.1.1+1.1.1.2+1.1.1.3+1.1.1.4=3.45+6.72+2.89+4.62=17.68`

Then `1.1=1.1.1+1.1.2+1.1.3+1.1.4=17.68+5.35+1.21+9.86=34.1`

Then `1=1.1+1.2+1.3=34.1+3.36+8.92=46.38`

Maybe I should turn the dict into a hierarchical dict first?

In fact it is originally a Series in pandas, but I guess it is hard to do that in pandas.

Comment: What does it look like in pandas? Chances are it'd be _easier_.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ almost same. df1=pd.Series(example)

Comment: `df1.to_frame().reset_index()['index'].str.split('.').apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).astype(int).sum().sum() / 10` and you get 5.0. Is that what you want?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm sorry,but I want to calculate `1.1.1=1.1.1.1+1.1.1.2+1.1.1.3+1.1.1.4=3.45+6.72+2.89+4.62=17.68`
Then `1.1=1.1.1+1.1.2+1.1.3+1.1.4=17.68+5.35+1.21+9.86=34.1`
Then `1=1.1+1.2+1.3=34.1+3.36+8.92=46.38`

Comment: @jezrael The example is confusing...Maybe `example2={'1.1.1.1':3.45,'1.1.1.2':6.72,'1.1.1.3':2.89,'1.1.1.4':4.62,'1.1.2':5.35,'1.1.3':1.21,'1.1.4':9.86,'1.2':3.36,'1.3':8.92}` is better? It seems a bad program question...

Comment: @goldmonkey i get it, check answer.

Comment: @goldmonkey - solution is not bad, only problem you dont post some code, what you try. Can you post it?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you very much.I post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Series` first and then [`Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by count of `.` by [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html), aggregate `sum`. Then swap order by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with `[::-1]` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

Last rename `index` values by `dict`, [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
example = {
    '1': np.nan, '1.1': np.nan, '1.1.1': np.nan, '1.1.1.1': 3.45,
    '1.1.1.2': 6.72, '1.1.1.3': 2.89, '1.1.1.4': 4.62,
    '1.1.2': 5.35, '1.1.3': 1.21, '1.1.4': 9.86,
    '1.2': 3.36, '1.3': 8.92
}
s = pd.Series(example)

d = { x: '.'.join(['1'] * x )  for x in range(7)}
print (d)
{0: '', 1: '1', 2: '1.1', 3: '1.1.1', 4: '1.1.1.1', 5: '1.1.1.1.1', 6: '1.1.1.1.1.1'}

df=s.groupby(s.index.str.count('\.')).sum().rename(d).rename_axis('a') \
    .iloc[::-1].cumsum().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df)
       a      b
0  1.1.1  17.68
1    1.1  34.10
2      1  46.38
3           NaN
```

And if necessary some cleaning:

```
df=s.groupby(s.index.str.count('\.')).sum().rename(d).rename_axis('a') \
   .iloc[1:].iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1].rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df)
       a      b
0      1  46.38
1    1.1  34.10
2  1.1.1  17.68
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my answer

```
example={
    '1':None,'1.1':None,'1.1.1':None,'1.1.1.1':3.45,
    '1.1.1.2':6.72,'1.1.1.3':2.89,'1.1.1.4':4.62,'1.1.2':5.35,
    '1.1.3':1.21,'1.1.4':9.86,'1.2':3.36,'1.3':8.92}
for key,value in example.items():
    if value is None:
        example[key]=0
for key in reversed(list(example.keys())):
    if '.' in key:
        parent='.'.join(key.split('.')[0:-1])
        example[parent]+=example[key]
print(example)
```